# Exact adjective of "conundrum"

Tags: single-word-requests, neologisms

I am about to coin the word 'conundrous' because I needed it (and I think it deserves a place in the dictionary)!

I would like comments on what you think about using 'conundrous' in the context of a serious article. But if you can supply one or more adjectives that are synonymous with 'conundrous', that would also be the answer for me. :)

If there are none, I will be happy to accept close synonyms (here's the definition of [conundrum](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conundrum) in the sense that I'd like to use it)

I'm after the "difficult problem" (but not the "pun") synonymity. It's used to describe a word from an ancient text which is seemingly not in the dictionaries; hard to find information about.

There's *enigmatic*, but it's just a mystery for the moment; it's not something that is by definition mysterious.

There's *elusive*, but I think that carries the connotation of something forever escaping one's reach.

Comment: I think *conundrous* doesn't sound well; I prefer *conundrummy* or *conundroumy*, which are less pompous

Comment: Google reveals that there are some occurrences of *"conundral"*.

Comment: @MarkBeadles, and also conundrical, which to me seems better language-wise but perhaps not in other aspects.

Comment: @jwpat7, I can't help but feel that just adding -y or -ish is a last resort.

Comment: @MarkBeadles, +1 for making at least consider trying stuff out in Google. Conundric has also been used, but that sounds a bit like geologic, simply experimental and a bit "off" ;p I know the dangers of going by search result counts - conundrous gives by far the most results now that I tried it, but all the results are hooey (which to a smartass could very well seem the adjective of the noun hooey). :)

Comment: Conundrous is actually already a neologism, if I would consider this. http://www3.merriam-webster.com/opendictionary/newword_search.php?word=con&last=130 - now, Merriam-Webster to me seems a bit too lax for comfort at times, opinions on this? And also whether conundrous is still sounding too pretentious.

Comment: @HenrikErlandsson, You can make up as many new words as you want. The thing is whether those words would remain in common use.

Comment: @AlexB., well, for me the important thing is whether someone will get a hangup reading the word and question the sincerity of the article.

Comment: hmm. knotty problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perplexing) gives the word *perplexing*, which encompasses the following synonyms:

> puzzling, complex, confusing, complicated, involved, hard, taxing, difficult, strange, weird, mysterious, baffling, bewildering, intricate, enigmatic, mystifying, inexplicable, thorny, paradoxical, unaccountable, knotty, labyrinthine

Comment: Thanks, as I finished the draft just now I considered "perplexing mere appendix of x" (as it appears as a mere mention (and an ambiguous one at that) at the end of a sentence, yet is vital to the account).

Comment: I like it, it hints at the "getting stumped reading it" aspect of it. I'm leaning towards spelling it out as the "perplexing mere appendix (and ambiguously appended at that!), x," rather than trying to find the optimal single word adjective.

Answer (score 5):

**Inscrutable** is an extremely close synonym for the "difficult problem" definition.

Comment: That's pretty good. I looked it up. For me, it hints at impossibility, as do the two synonyms I provided. Am I wrong about that in this case?

Comment: I don't think it carries implications of impossibility.  An inscrutable thing can be difficult, even vexing, but not necessarily insurmountable.

Answer (score 3):

***Puzzling***. A *conundrum* is a puzzle or difficult problem, often a riddle. The word is pseudo-Latin; it was coined at Oxford in the 1590's [according to OEtD](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=conundrum). By 1790 its meaning had evolved to more or less what it is today.

Comment: The *carborundum conundrum* is a tough nut to crack.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm after the "difficult problem" (but not the "pun") synonymity. It's used to describe a word from an ancient text which is seemingly not in the dictionaries; hard to find information about.

IMO, [*obscure*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obscure), [*arcane*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arcane) or [*esoteric*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/esoteric) might be a better fit than "conundrous".